# How to optimally find the total no of orders canceled, processed, pending, shipped from the Order collection?

Tags: orders, collection, query

How to find the number of orders canceled, processed, pending etc from the order collection. Currently I am clearing the loaded collection and applying the filters and calling count. So for all the status I am getting the count. But When checked the mysql logs I understand that its making lot of queries, Is there way I can do it optimally.?

Answer (score 1):

you can get it like that

```
<?php 
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()

$collection->getSelect()->group('status');
   echo  count($orders->getAllIds());
     ?>
```

you can get it direct query

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
$sel_qry = "SELECT COUNT(*),`status` FROM sales_flat_order  GROUP BY  `status`";
$selected = $readconnection->fetchAll($sel_qry);
```

Comment: Then for all status I have to do it right ? So If there is 7 status then 7 time the collection is loaded. Is there a way  I can do it in a single operation like using Mysql Group command or something

Comment: you can use the query method to get the result...